# React-router does not render anything if routes are changed in render()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For some reason, my routes only render half the time - seems like a race condition of some sort. It'll print out the "OK" but nothing from the routes, not even the 404. Pretty clear cut.

If I remove the loading bit it'll always render the switch block as intended.

Is there a better / different way to do this?

v4.2.0

```
  render() {
    const { hasInitialized } = this.props;
    if (!hasInitialized) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
        <Helmet titleTemplate="%s - Resilient" defaultTitle="Resilient" />
        <div>OK</div>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect from="/" to="/auth/check" exact={true} />
          <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />

          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/x" component={AdminLayout} />
          <Route component={Miss404} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5621

Comment: No clue why your code isn't working as it should, looks good to me... Do you have a real need for this loading conditional render, though? I see nothing in the routing that requires outside data, but maybe you left that out on purpose? My point being, could you delegate that conditional to one of the components being routed to?

Comment: Thanks Jaxx. I did leave out a bunch of code for simplicity. I'm just trying to load the user via a fetch call before anything happens. Moving this logic downstream doesn't make sense since it would have to be everywhere. I guess I'll try to bounce them to a route that handles the auth and then sends them back, but I was trying to avoid that since it's kind of a crummy UX. I've tried a whole bunch of things similar to the code above, and it seems like react-router just doesn't support changing routes in render.

Comment: Found a workaround with a combination of two things. 1) I created a HOC that wraps my all my routing logic. 2) I moved my initial history-changing logic from `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount`. Not sure why this makes it work, but happy to have a workaround.

Comment: Grats! You should write a detailed answer about how you did it if/when you have a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the react-router docs many times, and the part about [Blocked Updates](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) seems relevant. But, when I put a debugger line in `<Layout />`, location and history always have the right info, and still, none of the routes would render.

I still don't understand what the issue was, but here's the workaround I came up with. The code below wraps my `<Layout />` component, which contains all the routes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import LocalStorageManager from 'utils/LocalStorageManager';
import { selectCurrentUser, selectHasInitialized } from 'client/selectors/authSelectors';
import { setAccessToken, getProfile } from 'shared/api';
import { setHasInitialized, signIn } from 'modules/auth/actions.js';
import SinglePageCard from 'components/layout/SinglePageCard';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentUser: selectCurrentUser(state),
    hasInitialized: selectHasInitialized(state),
  };
};

export default (WrappedComponent) => {
  class Layout extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      const accessToken = LocalStorageManager.getAccessToken();
      if (!accessToken) {
        this.props.setHasInitialized();
        return;
      }

      setAccessToken(accessToken);
      getProfile().then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const { user } = response.data.data;
        this.props.signIn(user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.props.setHasInitialized();
      });
    }

    render() {
      const { currentUser, hasInitialized, ...rest } = this.props;
      if (!hasInitialized) {
        return (
          <SinglePageCard>
            <div>Initializing...</div>
          </SinglePageCard>
        );
      }

      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...rest} />
      );
    }
  }
  return withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { setHasInitialized, signIn })(Layout));
};
```